# Performance implications of a table with many fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table that is currently at 40 fields. A significant expansion of its capability now has it looking like something more like 100 fields.

What are the database and Rails performance implications of having a table with more fields? My understanding of relations is that they don't load the data until absolutely necessary, but would having so much more information slow down, say, a filtered index of these records (showing only the main 8-10 fields)?

The fields I'm specifically talking about adding are not relevant to any of my reports or most of my queries - they simply store data that is used on the back end.

Normalization is not a problem here (there are no fields like `field1`, `field2`, ..., for example). I know it's hard to answer these questions when posed in a qualitative manner, but is it likely better to build these 60 fields in this table, or should I create a separate 1-1 table for them?

Answer (score 0):

Having a single table is not a big deal and make things easier when it comes to queries. So if it's relevant, no need to split.

Still, you should only query what you need in your views so use the `ActiveRecord`'s `select`: [doc here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having a lot of fields will slow down access to the table, however, in general not significantly enough that it matters for average data sizes. Most SQL databases arrange tables row by row, so on the disk, first all 40 fields of row 1, then all 40 fields of row 2, and so on, are stored. This means, that if you are only interested in retrieving the first 2 fields, you will still read all other 38 fields and then jump to the next row that matches. This is not a big issue if you have only a few matching rows, but might be, if you would have many matches that are also consecutive.

That said, I would still heavily advice against a table with 40 fields, except when there is a very good reason to do so (which you might have, but you give to little details to answer this). In general, having that many fields indicates the use of some alternative design. Definitly, if what I wrote above starts becoming an issue, you should order the fields according to the access patterns (so if normally fields 1-10 and 20,24,25,30 are accessed together, put those groups into separate tables).